# How to find a specific point in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry

Let  $x_1,x_2,a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be distinct points. How can I find $a' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in such that the following is true? 
$$
\Vert a'-x_1 \Vert > \Vert a-x_1 \Vert\qquad\hbox{and}\quad\Vert a'-x_2 \Vert > \Vert a-x_2 \Vert
$$

Comment: All you require is that $a'$ is farther away from both $x_1$ and $x_2$ than $a$ is. What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the conditions into English.
The first condition $\|a' - x_1\| > \|a - x_1\|$ says "$a'$ is further from $x_1$ than $a$ is." The second condition $\|a' - x_2\| > \|a - x_2\|$ says "a' is further from $x_2$ than $a$ is."

Now let's draw a picture. This is really a question about distances. Let's let $R_1$ be the distance from $a$ to $x_1$ and let's let $R_2$ be the distance from $a$ to $x_2$. All the points further from $x_1$ than $a$ lie in the complement of $B_{x_1}(R_1)$ and all the points further from $x_2$ than $a$ lie in the complement of $B_{x_2}(R_2)$. So just pick a point that lies in the intersection of those two sets.

If you need to exhibit a *specific* point ...

> note that all three points lie in a ball of radius $R = \max\{ \|a\|, \|x_1\|, \|x_2\| \}$. Then let $a' = (3R, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$ and use the triangle inequality to show that it satisfies your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the line from $x_1$ to $x_2$.  Drop a perpendicular $ap$ to that line passing thru $a$.  Extend line $pa$ in the direction of $a$ by the length of $pa$, giving the point $a'$.

Note that if $x_1,x_2,a$ are colineal you can instead choose $a'$ to be along the line they are on, more than twice the largest distance among the three away from $a$.

Comment: I had exactly the same idea, but now try to show that this point, fulfils the requirements, I didn't achieve to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf{e}$ be any unit vector perpendicular to $x_2-x_1$. Choose $k$ greater than $\max(\Vert a-x_1\Vert, \Vert a-x_2\Vert)$. Now $x_1+k\mathbf{e}$ will do the trick.